# unix domain socket - securing receiver

Tags: sockets, unix

I am studying a [tutorial](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html) on unix domain socket. I have a question on the receiver part.

If a process is using listen() and waiting for incoming requests:

- what options does it have to make itself secure ? Does it have a way to identify who sent the request ? Can it apply some restriction on who can send it a request ?
- Is the situation that there is there no security option and if a process uses listen() its completely open to any request ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general thought on Linux is that security is enforced by the file permissions on the UNIX socket "file" in the filesystem. A process must have read/write access to the socket special file.

The [`unix(7)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) indicates:

> In the Linux implementation, sockets which are visible in the
>          filesystem honor the permissions of the directory they are in.  Their
>          owner, group, and permissions can be changed.  Creation of a new
>          socket will fail if the process does not have write and search
>          (execute) permission on the directory the socket is created in.
>          Connecting to the socket object requires read/write permission.  This
>          behavior differs from many BSD-derived systems which ignore
>          permissions for UNIX domain sockets.  Portable programs should not
>          rely on this feature for security.

It seems that directory-searching permissions *are* honored everywhere, though. So your socket can only be `connect()`ed to by users that have execute access on the entire path to your socket special file - this is true on all OSes.

**Related:**

- [Can UNIX Domain Sockets be locked by user ID?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11976/can-unix-domain-sockets-be-locked-by-user-id)
- [Which systems do not honor socket read/write permissions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83032/which-systems-do-not-honor-socket-read-write-permissions)

Comment: So the file must be owned by the receiver and the sender gets subjected to ACL when connecting ?

Comment: @Jake Yes. I'm looking for a source now, but I'm fairly confident it works just like one would expect it to.

Comment: @Jake On linux, and many other systems, the file permission bits are honored(see [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html#NOTES)). A process needs r/w access to connect to a unix socket, which you can manage in the usual way with user/group/other permissions or with [posix acls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setfacl.1.html)